# Does there exist an embedding $W^{k+m,1}(\mathbb{R}^3) \subseteq W^{k,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The literature on Sobolev embeddings can be rather confusing.  Let me emphasize that I am speaking about the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not a bounded domain.  By $W^{j,p}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ I mean the Sobolev space of $L^p$ functions whose (weak) partial derivatives of order $\leq j$ also lie in $L^p$.

Comment: A good starting point is to ask if this can hold for $k=m=0$... More explicitly: is $L^1(\mathbb{R}^3) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ true? Just to understand: why would the literature on Sobolev spaces be rather confusing?

Comment: No of course it is false when $k=m=0$.. all I meant by that comment was that different texts phrase them differently, some texts only have the inclusions for bounded domains $\Omega$, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working on $\mathbb R^n$, you should check the scaling property first. Suppose we dilate a function $u$ by factor $\lambda$, that is consider $x\mapsto u(\lambda^{-1}x)$. The $k$th order derivatives  acquire the factor of $\lambda^{-k}$, and another $\lambda^n$ comes from the change of variable in the integral. The total effect on $\int |D^k u(x)|\,dx$ is multiplication by $\lambda^{n-kp}$.

In order to have an embedding $W^{k,p}\subseteq W^{m,s}$ on $\mathbb R^n$, both spaces must scale in the same way: that is, 
$$ kp =  ms$$
In your setting, this requires $k+m=2k$, that is $m=k$.

To see whether for $m=k$ the result holds, you can argue as follows:

1. Smooth compactly supported functions are dense in Sobolev spaces of all orders, for   all finite $ p$.
2. Rescaling such a function, we can put its support into the unit ball. (Scaling is ok by the above.)
3. Apply the Sobolev embedding   for the unit ball, **if** the exponents fit.

The exponents fit  if 
$$\frac{1}{2}\ge \frac{1}{1}-\frac{m}{3}$$ 
which is to say,  $m\ge 2$.